# OnNavigationItemSelected() not opening the required fragments

Tags: java, android

So I've written up an activity which uses a drawer menu that is supposed to open fragments when I click on one of the items in the menu. The `onNavigationItemSelected` method here is:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment());
            break;

        case R.id.nav_settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_requests:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new RequestsFragment()).commit();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_messages:
            moveToMessageActivity();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_help:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I am indeed implementing `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in my activity. I have the ProfileFragment(), RequestFragment(), SettingsFragment() as well as the method `moveToMessageActivity()` all in my project.
I've read a few posts about a similar issue in which the problem was with the layout activity but their solutions did not work for me.
Here's my xml (all of which is enclosed in an `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayoutDrawerLayout`) tag:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDashboard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dashboard_patient_home_page"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textDashboard"
            android:textColor="@color/quantum_grey300"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo_activity_patient_home_page"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_profile_medical_mask" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/quantum_grey200"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="88dp"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_newrequest_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/new_request_home_icon"
                        android:textColor="#5C5C5C"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/quantum_grey200"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="88dp"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_location_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/location_update"
                        android:textColor="#5C5C5C"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/quantum_grey200"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="88dp"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_messages_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/messages_home_icon"
                        android:textColor="#5C5C5C"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                app:cardElevation="6dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/quantum_grey200"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="88dp"
                        android:layout_height="88dp"
                        android:contentDescription="TODO"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_settings_icon" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="@string/settings_home_icon"
                        android:textColor="#5C5C5C"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
```

I am not sure why the selected menu items are not responding when they are being selected. Any and all help in solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First in `case R.id.nav_profile:` you forgot `commit`
in

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
```